# Pytorch/Pytorch Lightning `state_dict()` cause ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm storing several pytorch-lightning modules in a list. Then I loop through them and do: `[m.state_dict() for m in models]`, after this I get the `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists`. More detail:

```
File ...torch/distributed/_sharded_tensor/__init__.py", line 334, in state_dict_hook
    _recurse_update_dict(module, destination, prefix)
File ...torch/distributed/_sharded_tensor/__init__.py", line 357, in _recurse_update_dict
    if isinstance(attr, ShardedTensor):
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

I get that weakly-referenced errors would occur when some memory is freed related to the object, but I can't see anything like that.

Comment: Can you share the lines where you assign/initialize the ‘models’ variable?

Comment: This was a few month ago, so I don't have the code now. But I fixed it by upgrading pytorch.